# Como salvar e carregar dados de um .txt pra um gridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

Já faz dois dias que eu estou procurando ajuda para meu problema, mas tudo que acho não me serve. Estou fazendo um programa simples, como se fosse uma agenda, onde eu coloco todos os registros da minha loja. Não preciso de nada complicado.

Fiz um `DataGridView`, porém não conectado a uma database, quero que ele armazene suas informações em um arquivo `.txt` na mesma pasta. Preciso que ele salve separadamente os campos preenchidos no `GridView`, como nome, produto locado, valor pago, data e etc.

Porém preciso que seja tudo bem separado, e que quando eu abra o programa ele puxe todas essas informações salvas no arquivo de volta. Já fiz algumas tentativas, não achei nenhum método que salve os dados escritos no `GridView`.

Resumindo:

-Preciso saber como faço para ler o texto de uma célula do `GridView` e, desta forma, salvar este texto no meu arquivo `.txt`.

-Preciso saber como faço para puxar as informações do arquivo `.txt` , porém , com todas as informações separadas, ou seja, cada célula com
   sua devida informação.

Aqui está o que eu já fiz até agora:

```
namespace Cadastro_e_Informações_de_Clientes
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {                                   
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void bSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            //Fiz um botão para pegar os dados escritos nas text boxes (tNome, tLocacao, tProduto etc...) e passar-los para o GridView
            //Como eu ainda não sei um método de salvar o texto diretamente da célula do GridView, eu fiz isso para salvar no momento do cadastro.

            if (this.tNome.Text == String.Empty || this.tProduto.Text == String.Empty || this.tLocacao.Text == String.Empty || this.tVencimento.Text == String.Empty || this.tPago.Text == String.Empty || this.tDivida.Text == String.Empty || this.tAdicional.Text == String.Empty)
            {
                string mensagem = "Um dos campos de texto não foi preenchido.\nDeseja continuar?";
                string titulo = "Aviso!";
                MessageBoxButtons Botoes = MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel;

                DialogResult resultado = MessageBox.Show(mensagem, titulo, Botoes, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

                if (resultado == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    this.Planilha.Rows.Add(tNome.Text, tProduto.Text, tLocacao.Text, tVencimento.Text, tPago.Text, tDivida.Text, tAdicional.Text);
                    FileStream Dados = new FileStream("C:/Users/Win/Desktop/Empresa/Dados.txt", FileMode.Append);

                    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(Dados);
                    //grava uma string no arquivo
                    bw.Write(tNome.Text + "\t" + tProduto.Text + "\t" + tLocacao.Text + "\t" + tVencimento.Text + "\t" + tPago.Text + "\t" + tDivida.Text + "\t" + tAdicional.Text + "\n");
                    bw.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    string mCancelada = "Operação cancelada.";
                    string tCancelada = "Cancelado!";
                    MessageBoxButtons cBotoes = MessageBoxButtons.OK;
                    MessageBox.Show(mCancelada, tCancelada, cBotoes, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.Planilha.Rows.Add(tNome.Text, tProduto.Text, tLocacao.Text, tVencimento.Text, tPago.Text, tDivida.Text, tAdicional.Text);

                FileStream Dados = new FileStream("C:/Users/Win/Desktop/Empresa/Dados.@hR", FileMode.Append);

                BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(Dados);
                //grava uma string no arquivo
                bw.Write(tNome.Text + tProduto.Text + tLocacao.Text + tVencimento.Text + tPago.Text + tDivida.Text + tAdicional.Text);
                bw.Close();
            }
            tAdicional.Clear();
            tNome.Clear();
            tProduto.Clear();
            tVencimento.Clear();
            tPago.Clear();
            tDivida.Clear();
            tLocacao.Clear();
        }

        private void timerEditavel_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Esta é a opção de editar o GridView, porém, aqui está um de meus principais problemas.
            //Preciso ler o texto das células para que quando eu edite uma delas, eu possa ler as celulas e salvar no arquivo.txt.
            if (checkEditar.Checked)
            {
                cCliente.ReadOnly = false;
                cProduto.ReadOnly = false;
                cPago.ReadOnly = false;
                cAdic.ReadOnly = false;
                cVencimento.ReadOnly = false;
                cLocação.ReadOnly = false;
                cDivida.ReadOnly = false;
                timerEditavel.Stop();  
            }
            else
            {
                timerEditavel.Start();
                cCliente.ReadOnly = true;
                cProduto.ReadOnly = true;
                cPago.ReadOnly = true;
                cAdic.ReadOnly = true;
                cCliente.ReadOnly = true;
                cLocação.ReadOnly = true;
                cDivida.ReadOnly = true;
                //Isso abaixo foram as tentativas que fiz para ler as células. Más nenhuma delas lê realmente
                //o texto escrito nas células.
                tNome.Text = cCliente.ToString();
                tProduto.Text = cProduto.Index.ToString();
                tPago.Text = cPago.ToolTipText.ToString();
                tAdicional.Text = cPago.Index.ToString();
                tVencimento.Text = cVencimento.Index.ToString();
                tLocacao.Text = cLocação.Index.ToString();
                tDivida.Text = cDivida.Index.ToString();                
            }
        }

        private void checkTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!checkEditar.Checked)
            {
                timerEditavel.Start();
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Adiciona uma linha vazia ao GridView
            this.Planilha.Rows.Add("", "", "", "", "", "", "");
        }

        private void lTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lInfo.Text = "Preencha os campos mostrados acima com as informações do Cliente e clique no botão para salvar na planilha.\nOs dados serão mostrados na planilha da aba 'Cadastros' e serão salvos no arquivo 'dados.bin' na pasta do programa.\nNo caso de algum erro ou problema durante a utilização deste programa, por favor, clique na aba 'Ajuda' e digite o erro acontecido.\nAtualizações com mais optimizações e aperfeissoamentos do código poderão vir.\nObrigado!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Porque você não usa o Microsoft Access? Este aplicativo já tem opção de criar Tabela e Formulários que você pode montar.

Comment: Você pode criar uma roda nova e passar mais alguns dias tentando ou usar uma roda que já existe, acho muito melhor a 2ª opção

Comment: Concordo com os comentários anteriores, agora se existe algum impedimento em usar um banco de dados, já pensou em usar arquivos _xml_? Já tive de cria aplicações para _PDA´s_ e para persistir os dados usava _xml_. Com os comandos `.ReadXml` e `.WriteXml` é simples carregar e gravar o `DataGridView`.

Answer (score 5):

Concordo com o @LuisAlexandreRodrigues que o melhor seria salvar em um banco e dados, e Sqlite EF6 seria perfeito para este tipo de coisa.

mas vou considerar que existe a necessidade de salvar os dados em um arquivo texto que seja facilmente lido e compreendido por Humanos.

Neste caso acredito que o melhor formato ceja o CSV (apesar de XML ser um otimo candidato).

Para facilitar a vida, iremos utilizar um Nugget nos exemplos a seguir:
[LINQtoCSV](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqToCsv/)

Agora vamos ao codigo.

**Model**

```
public class Item
{
    [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 0, Name = "Nome", CanBeNull = false)]
    public String Nome { get; set; }

    [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 1, Name = "Produto", CanBeNull = false)]
    public String Produto { get; set; }

    [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 2, Name = "Locacao", CanBeNull = false)]
    public String Locacao { get; set; }

    [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 3, Name = "Vencimento", CanBeNull = false)]
    public DateTime Vencimento { get; set; }

    [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 4, Name = "Pago", CanBeNull = false, NumberStyle = NumberStyles.Currency)]
    public Decimal Pago { get; set; }

    [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 5, Name = "Divida", CanBeNull = false, NumberStyle = NumberStyles.Currency)]
    public Decimal Divida { get; set; }

    [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 6, Name = "Adicional", CanBeNull = false, NumberStyle = NumberStyles.Currency)]
    public Decimal Adicional { get; set; }
}
```

**Form - Load**

```
public partial class FrmPlanilha : Form
{
    private BindingSource source;
    private CsvFileDescription options;

    public FrmPlanilha()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.source = new BindingSource();
        this.options = new CsvFileDescription
        {
            SeparatorChar = ';',
            FirstLineHasColumnNames = true,
            FileCultureName = "pt-BR"
        };

        var context = new CsvContext();
        var itens = context.Read<Item>(@"C:\temp\itens.csv", options).ToList();

        this.source.DataSource = itens;
        this.dgvItens.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        this.dgvItens.DataSource = this.source;
    }
    ...
}
```

**Adicionar novo Item**

No exemplo a seguir este preenchendo o objeto Item com dados aleatorios, porém você deve faze-lo com dados reais.

```
private void btAdicionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var item = new Item
    {
        Nome = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        Produto = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        Locacao = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        Vencimento = DateTime.Now,
        Divida = 0,
        Pago = 0,
        Adicional = 0
    };

    var itens = this.source.List as List<Item>;
    itens.Add(item);

    this.dgvItens.DataSource = null;
    this.dgvItens.DataSource = this.source;
}
```

**Salvando**

```
private void btSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var context = new CsvContext();
    context.Write(this.source.List as List<Item>, @"C:\temp\itens.csv", this.options);
}
```

Comment: CSV é o caminho para esse tipo de dado ao meu ver, pois além de poder se manipulado pela tua aplicação outros programas de tabelas podem manipular o mesmo.

Answer (score 3):

Para complementar a resposta do Luis Alexandre:

Eu prefiro percorrer a um dataGridView da seguinte forma:

```
for(i=0;i < (SeuGrid.Rows.Count - 1);i++)
{
     DataGridViewTextBoxCell tnome = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)SeuGrid.Rows[i].Cell[1];
     DataGridViewTextBoxCell tproduto = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)SeuGrid.Rows[i].Cell[2];
     DataGridViewTextBoxCell tlocalizacao = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)SeuGrid.Rows[i].Cell[3];
     
     string nome = tnome.Value;
     string produto = tproduto.Value;
     string localizacao = tlocalizacao.Value;
}
```

embora pareça mais complicado, o uso do DataGridViewTextBoxCell pode permitir algumas vantagens a depender da aplicação, como alterar o valor da célula (`tnome.Value = "novo valor"`), caso necessário, etc...

para salvar em txt eu encontrei um bom link para se usar como guia:
http://imasters.com.br/artigo/12197/dotnet/leitura-e-escrita-em-arquivos-com-c/

Em cada linha você concatena as informações que quer numa linha.

Você pode dar o espaço que é necessário para você, pode fazer concantenando com uma string com espaços: `string spc = "       ";`

Eu não sei qual o seu objetivo, mas prefiro XML como o LuisAlexandre também sugeriu.

Answer (score 2):

Para ler o conteúdo do GridView você poderia tentar o seguinte:

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in SeuGridView.Rows)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < SeuGridView.Columns.Count, i++)
    {
        String header = SeuGridView.Columns[i].HeaderText;
        String cellText = row.Cells[i].Text;
    }
}
```

Para persistir os dados, acho que a melhor opção é utilizar algum banco de dados, como MS Access, MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.

Em todo caso, se a necessidade permitir salvar os dados em XML, tente utilizar a classe DataSet. Ela possui métodos para ler e escrever arquivos em XML. Veja:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.dataset.writexml(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score -3):

```
                  {
                    int row = 0;
                    dgwPedidoVenda.Rows.Add();
                    row = dgwPedidoVenda.Rows.Count - 1; //-2
                    dgwPedidoVenda["ID", row].Value = txtId.Text;
                    dgwPedidoVenda["Nome", row].Value = txtNome.Text;
                    dgwPedidoVenda["Produto", row].Value = txtProduto.Text;
                    dgwPedidoVenda["Vencimento", row].Value = txtVencimento.Text;
                 }
```